# Django static file inclusion

Tags: django, file, static

[image]

Below is my folder structure for django project. The remaining files are working well. When I load the polls app in chrome then I get the message 'going to be affected'. As you can see I have also included a css file to the project and in that css file I am doing nothing but giving normal styling.

```
p{
    background-color:red;
}
```

But when I load the app in the browser it is not showing background color as red.
In short there is no effect of the css file.
What I am doing wrong

Comment: in browser console, network tab, load the page, is there any 404 errors?

Comment: Are you using the Django Development server? If not, you surely have to [`./manage.py collectstatic`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django-admin-collectstatic)

Comment: @Yusef BH. Can you pls explain what you mean by loading in in browser console, network tab

Comment: @raratiru Yes I am using django development server. I am initialising with python manage.py runserver

Comment: [Have you set](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/) correctly the static files app? Please post from the `settings.py` the following: `STATIC_ROOT` `STATIC_URL` `STATICFILES_DIRS` `STATICFILES_STORAGE` `STATICFILES_FINDERS`.

Comment: @raratiru This is the only thing regarding static  STATIC_URL = '/static/'. Other than this the settings are regarding templates and installed apps and other things.

Comment: @NikhilRathore Supposing that you have correctly set the static files system, restart the development server and when you load the page, under the console logs of the server you should see a call to the `path/to/polls/first.css`. If this is not happening, since you see the text -ie the html file is called- try to connect through private mode in your browser which has no cached data to see if the browser cache is the problem.

Comment: Well I was able to solve this by naming the CSS file as style.css. other names are not working. Is it necessary to name it style.css